# SQL Server : Group By and Pivot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a SQL Server query to pull the data.

For example of my query :

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(Year, capDateTime) Year, 
    DATEPART(Month, capDateTime) Month, 
    SUM(CAST(amount AS MONEY)) [TotalAmount]
FROM 
    dbo.iso_main
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(Year, capDateTime), DATEPART(Month, capDateTime)
ORDER BY 
    Year, Month
```

Here is the result :

[image]

Now, I keep questioning myself how do I get a result like this:

```
|Month 7    | Month 8    |
+-----------+------------+
| 726800.00 | 2208400.00 |
```

I don't really care about the year and I just want to it return a row of months.

Comment: Just check [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) - it would be simple to implement here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        year(capDateTime) as [year],left(datename(month,icapDateTime),3)as [month], 
        CAST(amount AS money) as Amount 
    FROM dbo.iso_main
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount) 
    FOR [month] IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, 
    may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
)AS pvt
```

Check [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query) for further reading.

Comment: @Sector3 Mark this as accepted answer if it solved your problem.